# what is the best and fastest way to get the row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have the data in below format in my table, I have to fetch the decile, so what is the best and fastest Query in SQL server to get the correct decile.

suppose I have two parameters in my scalar function,

1. PerformanceValue
2. Measureid

suppose I pass 11.22 in performance value parameter and 3 in measureid, the scalar function should return 3

suppose I pass 85.54  in performance value parameter and 4 in measureid it returns 10

suppose I pass 54.00 in performance value parameter and 4 in measureid it return 7.2

[image: Decile Data]

Comment: The last case which you posted - is it supposed to return 7.2? Or was that supposed to read just 7? Is the image your current data format?

Comment: I suggest you normalize your table to store atomic values in each column and avoid the repeating group. It will then be easier to query simple and perform better too.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

The table you need contains `MeasureID`, the number range (e.g `from_value` and `till_value`) and `Decile`. Then use a simple `WHERE` clause:

```
select decile
from mytable
where measureid = 4
  and 54.00 between from_value and till_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned. The best course of action would be to correct the table design. Of course we all live in the real world and that bay not always be possible.

The following uses the idea of a "semi-perminant" table in tempdb. That will be updated with new measurements w/o having to reprocess the underlying based table with every execution. This should yield the fastest possible execution times short of a full table redesign & process redesign.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    Measured INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Decile_3 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Decile_4 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Decile_5 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Decile_6 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Decile_7 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Decile_8 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Decile_9 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Decile_10 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
    );
INSERT #TestData (Measured, Decile_3, Decile_4, Decile_5, Decile_6, Decile_7, Decile_8, Decile_9, Decile_10) VALUES
    (1, '54.67 - 35.91', '35.90 - 25.63', '25.62 - 19.34', '19.33 - 14.15', '14.14 -  9.10', ' 9.09 -  3.34', ' 3.33 -  0.01', '0'),
    (2, '53.85 - 64.74', '64.75 - 70.90', '70.91 - 86.68', '89.32 - 92.92', '92.91 - 96.54', '96.55 - 98.67', '96.55 - 98.67', '>= 98.68'),
    (3, '11.22 - 18.57', '18.58 - 24.99', '25.00 - 31.84', '31.85 - 38.92', '38.93 - 47.86', '47.87 - 59.99', '60.00 - 79.01', '>= 79.01'),
    (4, '14.13 - 23.25', '23.26 - 33.02', '33.03 - 43.58', '43.59 - 53.96', '53.97 - 63.60', '63.61 - 74.54', '74.55 - 85.52', '>= 85.53'),
    (5, '12.41 - 22.21', '22.22 - 32.30', '32.31 - 40.86', '40.87 - 47.91', '47.92 - 55.25', '55.26 - 63.06', '63.07 - 73.22', '>= 73.23');

-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td'

--======================================================================
--======================================================================

-- create a semi-perminant unpivot table in temp db that simply adds new measurement as opposed to
-- reporcessing the entire base table with every execution.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.UnpivotData', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN   -- DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.UnpivotData;
    CREATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.UnpivotData (
        Measured INT NOT NULL,
        dType TINYINT NOT NULL,
        BegRange DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
        EndRange DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Measured, dType) 
        );
END;
INSERT tempdb.dbo.UnpivotData (Measured, dType, BegRange, EndRange)
SELECT 
    td.Measured,
    d.dType,
    r.BegRange,
    r.EndRange
FROM 
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (3, td.Decile_3), (4, td.Decile_4), (5, td.Decile_5), (6, td.Decile_6), 
                            (7, td.Decile_7), (8, td.Decile_8), (9, td.Decile_9), (10, td.Decile_10) 
                            ) d (dType, dValue)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(' - ', d.dValue) > 0 THEN LEFT(d.dValue, 5)
                            WHEN LEFT(d.dValue, 2) = '>=' THEN RIGHT(d.dValue, 5)
                            WHEN LEFT(d.dValue, 2) = '<=' THEN '0'
                            ELSE d.dValue
                        END,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(' - ', d.dValue) > 0 THEN RIGHT(d.dValue, 5)
                            WHEN LEFT(d.dValue, 2) = '>=' THEN '9999999.99'
                            WHEN LEFT(d.dValue, 2) = '<=' THEN RIGHT(d.dValue, 5)
                            ELSE d.dValue
                        END
                        ) ) r (BegRange, EndRange)
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.UnpivotData ud WHERE td.Measured = ud.Measured);

-----------------------------------------------------------

-- Querieng from the temp table is now quite easy.
DECLARE 
    @Measure INT = 4,
    @PerformanceVal DECIMAL(9,2) = 85.54;

SELECT 
    ud.Measured,
    ud.dType,
    ud.BegRange,
    ud.EndRange
FROM 
    tempdb.dbo.UnpivotData ud
WHERE 
    ud.Measured = @Measure
    AND @PerformanceVal BETWEEN ud.BegRange AND ud.EndRange;
```

Results...

```
Measured    dType BegRange                                EndRange
----------- ----- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
4           10    85.53                                   9999999.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that may end up being faster as it starts by doing an index seek on Measurid so that only a single row of data needs to be parsed...

```
DECLARE
    @Measureid INT = 4729,
    @Value DECIMAL(9,2) = 85.0;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UnpivotData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #UnpivotData;

SELECT 
    td.Measureid,
    d.dType,
    BegRange = ISNULL(CAST(r.BegRange AS DECIMAL(9,2)), 0),
    EndRange = ISNULL(CAST(r.EndRange AS DECIMAL(9,2)), 0)
    INTO #UnpivotData
FROM 
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (3, td.Decile_3), (4, td.Decile_4), (5, td.Decile_5), (6, td.Decile_6), 
                            (7, td.Decile_7), (8, td.Decile_8), (9, td.Decile_9), (10, td.Decile_10) 
                            ) d (dType, dValue)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(' - ', d.dValue) > 0 THEN LEFT(d.dValue, 5)
                            WHEN LEFT(d.dValue, 2) = '>=' THEN RIGHT(d.dValue, 5)
                            WHEN LEFT(d.dValue, 2) = '<=' THEN '0'
                            ELSE d.dValue
                        END,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(' - ', d.dValue) > 0 THEN RIGHT(d.dValue, 5)
                            WHEN LEFT(d.dValue, 2) = '>=' THEN '9999999.99'
                            WHEN LEFT(d.dValue, 2) = '<=' THEN RIGHT(d.dValue, 5)
                            ELSE d.dValue
                        END
                        ) ) r (BegRange, EndRange)
WHERE 
    td.Measureid = @Measureid;

------------------------------------------------------

SELECT 
    ud.Measureid,
    ud.dType,
    ud.BegRange,
    ud.EndRange
FROM 
    #UnpivotData ud
WHERE 
    @Value BETWEEN ud.BegRange AND ud.EndRange;
GO
```